# Just finished installing Ubuntu Desktop 13.10, mouse clicking problem

Tags: mouse

Installed on my MacBook Pro Early 2011, and I've encountered this problem before where my mouse will move around the screen but won't select anything. I can't click to navigate anything and all has to be done through my keyboard. Just a little frustrating.

Any help?

**Update:** I found the problem to be linked to my mad catz gaming mouse. When I have it plugged in, the cursor does as mentioned, but when I unplug it, everything's fine. But in-case this problem ever happens to me, an answer will still work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew exactly what your problem was before your comment because I also own a RAT and took me forever to figure out what to google for.

Basically what you need to do is manually map all the buttons in the `xorg`.
[Here is the link to the solution.](http://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/using-the-cyborg-r-a-t-7-with-ubuntu/)

What is happening is your RAT needs a driver and linux isn't taking the button inputs correctly. **Your symptom is due to the fact that it doesn't know how to click off.** This gives it the illusion that none of your buttons are working. One workout around until you fix this is to unplug/replug or change mouse modes (RAT 7 and 9 only). You will get one click each time. Or just use a different mouse until you make the changes.